# How to use a constraint to make a roller paint animation?

Tags: animation, constraints

:)

I found a tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/xrw7-cbtQBA) on Youtube that shows how to make a painting animation with Dynamic Paint. It works, but I can't figure out why the roller stops rotating after a while. You can download the file [here on OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am7IV_H-qRu3cuyV8f1iUApPHYw?e=2yaeWW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the stick movement control the rotation of the roller:

- Create your object, parent the roller to the stick:

[image]

- Give your roller a *Transformation* constraint with this kind of setup: Stick as *Target*, *Extrapolation* on, *Target* and *Owner > Local Space*, *Map From > Location* with the stick local movement orientation as axis (choose for example -1 and 1 as value, anyway it will be extrapolated), *Map To > Rotation* with the roller rotation movement axis as destination axis, don't forget to select the target location axis as *Source* (and choose the rotation value that will match):

[image]

Move the stick, the roller should rotate according to the stick speed:

[image]